# Red Hat Service Mesh: custom header transformed into x-b3-traceId is lost

Tags: openshift, istio

I am trying to integrate a legacy system with microservice hosted on Red Hat OpenShift platform. The service is a java app behind ingress gateway.
The legacy app passes unique operation identifier as a custom header `uniqueId`. The microservice leverages openshift service mesh support for Jaeger so I can pass tracing headers such as `x-b3-traceid` and see the request trace in Jaeger UI. Unfortunately, the legacy app cannot be modified and won't send jaeger headers but `uniqueId` conforms jaeger rules and seems ok to be used for tracing.

I am trying to transform `uniqueId` into `x-b3-traceid` on an envoy filter. The problem is that I can copy it to any other header, but cannot modify `x-b3-*` headers. Istio keeps generating new set of `x-b3-*` headers no matter what I do in envoy filter. See filter code below.

I tried different filter positions (on ingress gateway, on pod sidecar, before envoy.router, etc). Seems nothing works. Can anyone recommend how can I pass custom header as a traceId for service mesh's jaeger? I can create a custom proxy service transforming one header with another but it looks redundant. Is it possible to achieve that with service mesh only?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: call-id-filter
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  filters:
    - filterConfig:
        inlineCode: |
          function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
            headers = request_handle:headers()
            uniqueId=headers:get("uniqueId")
            if (uniqueId ~= nil) then
              request_handle:headers():add("x-b3-traceid", uniqueId) -- istio overwrites these values
              request_handle:headers():add("x-b3-spanid", "myspan")
              request_handle:headers():add("x-b3-sampled", "1")

              request_handle:headers():add("my-custom-unique-id", uniqueId) -- works fine
              
              request_handle:logCritical("envoy filter setting x-b3-traceid with"..uniqueId)
            end
          end
      filterName: envoy.lua
      filterType: HTTP
      insertPosition:
        index: FIRST
      listenerMatch:
        listenerType: GATEWAY
        portNumber: 9011
  workloadLabels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
```